# Cheapest way to get a court order for Amazon

Tags: defamation

My company is being severely defamed by a post on a website hosted by Amazon's cloud hosting service (AWS). Amazon declines to remove the website/post without a court order. The site's owner (anonymous) simply doesn't answer any of my requests. What is the cheapest way to get the court order to Amazon?

I'm based in Singapore and anything related to the US legal system is extremely expensive here.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the so-called [Section 230 protections](http://ideas.time.com/2013/01/07/yelp-reviewers-beware-you-can-get-sued/) (named after the relevant 47 U.S.C. § 230) apply to Amazon reviews and so Amazon can not be sued here. You need to sue the writer of the review in a competent jurisdiction and winning that lawsuit will result in removing that review.

For example, [this case](http://ideas.time.com/2013/01/07/yelp-reviewers-beware-you-can-get-sued/) explicitly says:

> the Virginia Supreme Court agreed. If Perez’s reviews prove to be defamatory—if they are false and they injured Dietz’s reputation— Dietz can collect monetary damages. But he has no right to get the reviews taken down while the courts try to figure out who is right.

Edit: Now that the question was edited... Your hope of finding a court where you can get an order for Amazon or the website operator or anyone to suspend a website is against Section 230. Check Global Royalties, Ltd. v. Xcentric Ventures, LLC, 544 F. Supp. 2d 929 (D. Ariz. 2008) for a very relevant example. Think about it: what would the world become if anyone could take down a web page with a simple email or even a mail written by a lawyer? That can't be.

In other words, you start with

> My company is being severely defamed

That's what you say. Who is to determine whether you are right? Perhaps a neutral third party who is well versed in the relevant legal texts? What about calling said neutral third party a court of law?

Comment: Thanks. This is not about an Amazon review but about a post on a site hosted on Amazon's cloud service (AWS). Let me edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Of course you are right and I understand the system works this way for very good reasons. However, I find it very frustrating that I can't do anything to stop somebody from spreading false information about my company, pretending to be a client. I can easily prove this anonymous person is not a client, but I can't afford a legal battle overseas. I guess I'll just have to resign to this?

Comment: There are two ways to fight bad speech: with suppression or with more speech. Some jurisdictions, particularly the US, are very keen on free speech and expect you to deal with bad speech with more speech (or ignore it). Other jurisdictions might be more open to an interlocutory injunction pending resolution of a defamation claim, but it is generally not looked at kindly by courts. Your best bet may be to help your actual clients spread as much truthful, favourable information about your business, so that the defamatory statement in question becomes an anomaly, a blip.